Determine the next position of the proper prefix of the pattern string
When I learn Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm, I got a function f from the book Fundamentals of Data Structures in C.
If p="p0 p1 ...p(n-1)" is a pattern, then its failure function, f, is defiened as:

f(j)= largest i<j such that p0 p1 ... p(i) = p(j-i) p(j-i+1) ... p(j), if such an i>=0 exists
f(j)= -1, otherwise.

Here's its restatement:
f(j)= -1, if j=0
f(j)= f_m(j-1)+1, where m is the least integer k for which p[f_k(j-1) + 1]=p[j]
f(j)= -1, if there is no k satisfying the above
(note that f_1(j)=f(j) and f_m(j)=f(f_m-1(j)))

And I got a problem about the second line of the restatement of f.
Let me introduce my pseudocode conventions:

All strings are 0-based which means they start from position 0.
Denote a string as str[0:m] which means the string contains characters: str[0], str[1], ..., str[m].
The substring of str could be str[0:0], str[0:1], ...,etc.

Question:
If we know the value of f(j-1), we are determining the value of f(j).
Why does "after checking p[f(j-1) + 1] != p[j], the next potential position of f(j) is f(f(j-1))+1" ?
Here 're my thoughts:

A proper prefix of a string is a prefix that is not equal to the
string itself. A proper suffix of a string is a suffix  that is not
equal to the string itself. These imply that 0 < f(k).

pat[0:k] extends a character from pat[0:k-1].

(pat[0:k] = pat[0:k-1] + pat[k])

It implies that the longest proper prefix which is also a  proper
suffix of pat[0:k] at most extends a  character from the one  of
pat[0:k-1].  ( f(k)<=f(k-1)+1 )

p[f(j-1) + 1] != p[j] It implies that pat[0:f(j-1) + 1] is not the
longest proper prefix which is also a proper suffix of  pat[0:k].
(f(k)<=f(k-1))

By the previous disscusion, 0 < f(k) <= f(k-1).


Then, why does the next potential position of f(j) is f(f(j-1))+1, and we no need to checking the positions of f(k) in order of f(k-1), f(k-1)-1, f(k-1)-2, ..., 0 ?
Fundamentals of Data Structures in C
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm
https://cp-algorithms.com/string/prefix-function.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953514/how-to-understand-the-process-of-dfa-construction-in-kmp-algorithms/36954802#36954802
